# Run a netbeans maven project from a command line

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, command-line

I wrote a maven code in netbeans that in included  6 classes:

```
ColumnComparator.java
IQC.java
Main.java
MultipleLinearRegression.java
Overlap.java
PSResidualReduction.java
```

I want to compile and run it on linux terminal. I tried:

```
javac Main.java ColumnComparator.java IQC.java MultipleLinearRegression.java Overlap.java PSResidualReduction.java
```

and got compilation error. The problem is that in MultipleLinearRegression class, I used jama package to do Matrix computation, but in command line I do not know how I should modify dependencies. Hopefully you guys can help me.

Comment: I didn't know that *.java files contained maven code instead of Java code.

Comment: If its a Maven project then simply change to the project directory and type `mvn clean compile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Add these lines to your `pom.xml` (you might already have the `<build/>` and `<plugins/>` tag there). Make sure to set the `<mainClass/>` tag to point to your specific main class.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you run your program from command line:

```
mvn exec:java
```

This will not affect/change the behavior of your Netbeans setup so you will still be able to run the program from within Netbeans.